# Finding an index in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

This may be very simple but I have not been able to come up with a solution.

I am have a:

```
ObservableCollection<ProcessModel> _collection = new ObservableCollection<ProcessModel>();
```

This collection is populated, with many ProcessModel's.

My question is that I have an ProcessModel, which I want to find in my _collection.

I want to do this so I am able to find the index of where the ProcessModel was in the _collection, I am really unsure how to do this.

I want to do this because I want to get at the ProcessModel N+1 ahead of it in the ObservableCollection (_collection).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var x = _collection[(_collection.IndexOf(ProcessItem) + 1)];
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a nice way to check for null using linq? say when the index of + 1 is out of bounds.

Comment: @user101010101: Check for `i+1` value. It should not be greater than Length/Count of your ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Nikhil sorry I am new to this how do you do that?

Comment: How does this get the index? This gets the item at the index, below answer gets the index.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet Eh? IndexOf returns the index.

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410.aspx

Use:

```
_collection.IndexOf(_item)
```

Here is some code to get the next item:

```
int nextIndex = _collection.IndexOf(_item) + 1;
if (nextIndex == 0)
{
    // not found, you may want to handle this as a special case.
}
else if (nextIndex < _collection.Count)
{
    _next = _collection[nextIndex];
}
else
{
    // that was the last one
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `ObservableCollection` is a sequence, hence we can use `LINQ`

```
int index = 
_collection.Select((x,i) => object.Equals(x, mydesiredProcessModel)? i + 1 : -1)
           .Where(x => x != -1).FirstOrDefault();

ProcessModel pm =  _collection.ElementAt(index);
```

I already incremented your index to 1 where it matches your requirement.

**OR**

```
ProcessModel pm = _collection[_collection.IndexOf(mydesiredProcessModel) + 1];
```

**OR**

```
ProcessModel pm = _collection.ElementAt(_collection.IndexOf(mydesiredProcessModel) + 1);
```

**EDIT for Not Null**

```
int i = _collection.IndexOf(ProcessItem) + 1;

var x;
if (i <= _collection.Count - 1) // Index start from 0 to LengthofCollection - 1
    x = _collection[i];
else
    MessageBox.Show("Item does not exist");
```